# Override CSS property in external SVG image

Tags: css, svg

I have following html and svg files:

**home.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   span {
    filter: invert(100%)
   }
  </style
</head>
<body>
  <span><img src="my.svg" /></span>
  <div><img src="my.svg" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**my.svg**

```
<svg version="1.1"
 baseProfile="full"
 width="36" height="36"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />

</svg>
```

The two rectangle are being rendered: one light blue and second red, as expected.
How can I preserve red color of both images, by updating .svg code only?
Unfortunately, I cannot change the code of the html page, that hosts my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  There is no way to achieve what you want without modifying the HTML.

Once the SVG is loaded and rendered, it has no control over what CSS effects might be applied to it by the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how and why but if you give red you get cyan and if you give cyan you get red

```
<svg version="1.1"
baseProfile="full"
width="36" height="36"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#00FFFF" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Exactly. But my problem is that I have two images: the first one with CSS filter and the second is without.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with that style tag given in home.html change it to...

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <span><img src="my.svg" /></span>
  <div><img src="my.svg" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```